# laravel query builder not encapsulating strings

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

```
                /*
             * ajax submission
             * data[545][App\ReportNames][ReportID]: 545
               data[545][App\ReportNames][ReportName]: Cabinet Value
               data[545][App\ReportNames][ReportType]: PHP
               data[545][App\ReportNames][ObjectName]: CabinetValueReport
               data[545][App\ReportNames][ObjectType]: Code
               data[545][App\ReportNames][Comments]: ObjName refs Model
               data[545][App\ReportNames][Disabled][]: 0
             *
             */
            $data = $request->data[$Key[0]][$model][$column];
            if(!is_numeric($data)){
                $data = array_map('strval',$request->data[$Key[0]][$model][$column]);
                //"message": "array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array",
                $data = (string)$request->data[$Key[0]][$model][$column];
                //"message": "Array to string conversion",
                $data = "'".$data."'"; 
                // "message": "Array to string conversion",
                $data = $data->__toString(); 
                //"message": "Call to a member function __toString() on string",
            }
            $update->save(); //Array to string conversion ... sql clause with string values not enclosed by quotes
```

the Main issue I am encountering is that SQL querys built are not encapsulating the string values. So if I pass my $data straight to a model->save() command it generates this sql

```
update [ReportNames] set [Comments] = ObjName refs Model, [Disabled] = 0 where [ReportID] = 545
```

Obviously without wrapping the string parameters I cannot save this information. So this runs completely fine in sql server manager.

```
update [ReportNames] set [Comments] = 'ObjName refs Model', [Disabled] = 0 where [ReportID] = 545
```

any advice on how to modify string values sent in the request would be appreciated.

Comment: Laravel uses parameter binding, so it doesn't need to encapsulate strings. Ignore the generated SQL, unless it's throwing an error. If it is, then check the error message.

Comment: this is the error...."message": "Array to string conversion (SQL: update [ReportNames] set [Comments] = ObjName refs Model, [Disabled] = 0 where [ReportID] = 545)",

Comment: `Array to string conversion` has nothing to do with your SQL. `var_dump($data);` to see what it contains, or find out which update property is throwing this error.

Comment: ok I think I found something thank you for the hand holding if interested...https://pastebin.com/DHBicBXA

Comment: To conclude I had a 'checkbox' field where it should have been 'radio' this caused an extra array level to be added to the return thus giving me this dumb problem.